# Cloud masking removes buildings and roads

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, cloudmasking

I'm new to GEE and especially the cloud masking algorithms. I am trying to get a cloudless composite image of an area using ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image) but I'm aware that this method can wrongly detect buildings and bare ground as clouds. Is there any way to improve the code to exclude those areas? Would using QA_pixel be a better approach..? Another problem I'm facing is that an empty raster is produced when I export the composite image.

So my thought process was to use the Landsat 8 and 9 TOA collections filtered by date and area. I then applied cloud masking using the ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image) on each of the filtered images in the merged collection. After masking, I created a composite image from the collection.

This is what i currently have: [full code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/989e5643824ee8062ac8483630cae254)

```
// Load Landsat 8 top-of-atmosphere (TOA) input imagery.
var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT_TOA').filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-01','2021-12-31')).filterBounds(geometry).aside(print);
var landsat9 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_TOA").filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-01','2021-12-31')).filterBounds(geometry).aside(print);
var landsat = landsat8.merge(landsat9)

var scoredlandsat = landsat.map(function(image){
  var image2 = image.set('SENSOR_ID', 'OLI_TIRS')
  // Cloud score the image
  var scored = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image2);
  // Create a mask from the cloud score and combine it with the image mask.
  var mask = scored.select(['cloud']).lte(5);
  //Apply the mask to the image
  var masked = image.updateMask(mask);
  return masked
}).aside(print)

//create composite from cloud masked images
var composite = scoredlandsat.median(); //removes cloud cover
print('cloud filtered composite:', composite)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `simpleCloudScore()` docs:

> This is not a robust cloud detector, and is intended mainly to compare
> multiple looks at the same point for relative cloud likelihood.

I would definitely use the `QA_PIXEL` band.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it out and it is definitely better at not masking the built areas. But it seems that some clouds are not masked instead. I'm planning to use the end composite image in some classification algorithms. In that case, would the QA_PIXEL method still be best to use? [combined code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e7e6740579f2fed0728a00a8d975e39f)

Comment: Yes, you typically mask every image in a collection using the QA band, then reduce the collection to create the composite, typically calculating the median. Even if there are some clouds left in your individual images, the median is typically cloud free, unless your area of interest is insanely cloudy.